# 2 custom post-type and 1 taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I have 2 post types (job, resume) and sharing 1 custom taxonomy (cities)

it's for jobs in "New york" and it's also for jobseekers in "New york" (resume is the post-type for jobseeker)

```
 register_taxonomy(
  'city',
  array( 'job_listing', 'resume' ),
  array( 'hierarchical' => true,
        //'label' => 'Location', 
            'label' => __('Locations1', 'Locations2'),   // both of them shows "locations1" there is no "locations2" on resume
            //'query_var' => true, 
         'query_var' => 'location',
        //'rewrite' => true
         'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'locations' )
  )
```

);

It works ok but I need to know how to get them to displayed.

On backend, it shows ok but it's all total posts amounts.

```
 domain.com/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=city&post_type=job
 domain.com/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=city&post_type=resume
```

problem : these display all amount of posts. not each post_types.

On front-end, I need to show 2 lists

```
 "jobs in Newyork", "resumes in Newyork"
```

How can I get them?

Comment: It is fine to share a taxonomy across post types, and you're registering it correctly. The label parameter, however, only accepts a string. You are using the function __() where the first parameter is the string and the second is the text-domain for translations. The second parameter is never visible. You might find the following tutorial on [advanced rewrite rules](http://thereforei.am/2011/10/28/advanced-taxonomy-queries-with-pretty-urls/) helpful for creating prettier front-end URLS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For jobs in Newyork:

```
$query1 = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'job','city'=>'new-york') )
```

For resumes in Newyork:

```
$query2 = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'resume','city'=>'new-york') )
```

Is this what you need ?

Comment: yes that's what I need (I haven't tried yet) I am working on backend, Label name is not also working. it supposed to show "location2" on resume. but it's "location" and total amount. not each...

Comment: please see register_taxonomy part, am I doing right to share a taxonomy for 2 post-types?

Comment: Yes you can share a taxonomy for any number of posts-types you want

Comment: For label parameter refer this example :  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy

Comment: yes I will please wait for a while. it's too late here :)